# append string to the current string

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a single string ,for each addskill() the content should be append to the current string and it should be seperated with commas.

**skill.ts**

```
addskill(item){
    this.skill.push(item.name);
    this.skill.push(',');
    console.log(this.skill)
   }
```

The current code will give an object array,I need a single string.

Comment: replace last two lines of code with `return this.skill.join(',');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join function

```
addskill(item){
    this.skill.push(item.name);
    console.log(this.skill.join())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `this.skill.push(',');` and use `this.skill.join();` when you want the string

```
addskill(item){
    this.skill.push(item.name);
    console.log(this.skill.join())
   }
```